# Rails and prawn: using regex to format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I'm trying to grab HTML tags with regex to format using prawn's methods. I've got this so far:

```
def format(pdf, string)
  regex_string = "\n|" +
                 "<b>(.*)<\/b>|" +
                 "<h3>(.*)<\/h3>|" +
                 "<strong>(.*)<\/strong>|" +
                 "[^<\n]+"
  regex = Regexp.new(regex_string, Regexp::MULTILINE)
  tokens = string.gsub("\n", " ").gsub(/<br\s*\/?>/, "\n").scan(regex)
  tokens.each do |breaker|
    case breaker
    when "<b>(.*)<\/b>", "<strong>(.*)<\/strong>"
      pdf.text breaker.to_s, :size => 10
    when "<h3>(.*)<\/h3>"
      pdf.text breaker.to_s, :size => 16
    else
      pdf.text breaker.to_s, :size => 10, :leading => 1
    end
  end
end
```

I think my regex is wrong though and I cannot figure out what it should be. I'm getting a rather weird array printout with that method. Any help'd be great!

**UPDATE**

Changing `(.*)` to `(.*?)` got the right tags in Rubular, but all the outputs except those in the HTML tags above are `[nil, nil, nil]` in threes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without actually testing it myself, it could be operating on empty array elements.  Try something like:

```
tokens = string.gsub("\n", " ").gsub(/<br\s*\/?>/, "\n").scan(regex).compact
```

For general HTML parsing, Nokogiri is probably the best option out there (for Rails):

- https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri
- http://nokogiri.org/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Turns out Nokogiri was way better at what I wanted.

Comment: Shoot, if I had known you were open to that, I'd have suggested it! Doesn't get much better for parsing HTML in rails.  I'll update my answer to reflect that.